# How to implement generic GetById() where Id can be of various types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, repository-pattern

I am trying to implement a generic `GetById(T id)` method which will cater for types which may have differing ID types. In my example, I have an entity which has an ID of type `int`, and one of type `string`.

However, I keep getting an error and I have no idea why:

*The type 'int' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TId' in the generic type of method IEntity*

**Entity Interface:**

To cater for my domain models which can have Id's of type `int` or `string`.

```
public interface IEntity<TId> where TId : class
{
    TId Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Entity Implementations:**

```
public class EntityOne : IEntity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other model properties...
}

public class EntityTwo : IEntity<string>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    // Other model properties...
}
```

**Generic Repository Interface:**

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity : class, IEntity<TId>
{
    TEntity GetById(TId id);
}
```

**Generic Repository Implementation:**

```
public abstract class Repository<TEntity, TId> : IRepository<TEntity, TId>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<TId>
    where TId : class
{
    // Context setup...

    public virtual TEntity GetById(TId id)
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

**Repository Implementations:**

```
 public class EntityOneRepository : Repository<EntityOne, int>
    {
        // Initialise...
    }

    public class EntityTwoRepository : Repository<EntityTwo, string>
    {
        // Initialise...
    }
```

Comment: Why are you restricting `TId` to `class` types?  That won't work with `int` (the error message makes that pretty clear).  `class` means "reference type" in generic constraints.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should remove the constraint on TId from your `Repository` class

```
public abstract class Repository<TEntity, TId> : IRepository<TEntity, TId>
where TEntity : class, IEntity<TId>
{
    public virtual TEntity GetById(TId id)
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: This suggestion resolves the reference type error, however, I am now getting an `Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type TId and TId` error when trying to perform the match by Id

Comment: Turns out it works fine if I use `.Find(id)` instead of `.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)`. I would expect it is doing the exact same thing behind this method though, so not sure why `.Find()` is valid.

Comment: for the ```.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id == id)``` error, you could also use ```.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id.Equals(id))```

Answer (score 6):

```
public interface IEntity<TId> where TId : class
{
    TId Id { get; set; }
}
```

The `where TId : class` constraint requires every implementation to have a Id which derives from object which is not true for value types like int.

Thats what the error message tells you: `The type 'int' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TId' in the generic type of method IEntity`

Just remove the constraint `where TId : class` from `IEntity<TId>`

Answer (score 2):

To your question: 
***I am trying to implement a generic GetById(T id) method which will cater for types which may have differing ID types. In my example, I have an entity which has an ID of type int, and one of type string.***

```
    public virtual TEntity GetById<TId>(TId id)
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
```

For generic parameter, just make a generic method like above