# Generic base class in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My Base class

```
 public interface IEntity<TId> where TId : class
    {
        TId Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class EntityOne : IEntity<int>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        // Other model properties...
    }
```

I am referencing this question [implement generic GetById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779723/how-to-implement-generic-getbyid-where-id-can-be-of-various-types)

I have Created my domain model EntityOne. but showing below  error

Error Showing "the type int must be reference type"

Pls, suggest.

Comment: [Read the docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)

Comment: The answers in your linked question already answers your question.
The constraint `class` requires a reference type and `ìnt` still isn't a reference type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `TId` is constrained to being a *reference type*, thats what `where TId: class` means.

If you want `TId` to be any type, then remove the constraint. If you want it to be only a value type, then the constaint should be `where TId: struct`. If neither of those are possible, then `TId` cannot be `int`.